# eclipse is not using application.yml

Tags: java, spring-boot, yaml

application.yml

```
server:
   port: 9001
```

application.properties

```
server.port= 9001
```

code works when I use .properties file but when I am using .yml file no properties are set and it runs on default port 8080. kindly help me with this issue

Comment: 8080 is the default. What's the problem with it running on port 8080 if you didn't specify anything else?

Comment: It Is not reading configurations and properties from application.yml but works fine when I use application.properties. server.port is just an example. I am not able to use application.yml file in my project.

Comment: Do you have both files? Does it work if you have an `application.yml` in your `resources` directory but no `application.properties`?

Comment: no I don't have both files. It's just not working either ways

Answer (score 0):

Application.yml is required to be on root of your application. So it seems eclipse is not finding it on root. Try changing the working directory in your eclipse run configuration. For example it can be /target/classes

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse application.yml not work You can try to use application.yaml I'm also facing same issue I used application.yaml then it work perfectly and make sure path will be src/main/resource